# Help creating Multiple InfoWindows using Google Maps

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I am creating a php page that loads cordinates from a mysql table and use them to create markers on a google map. It works fine. I also added Info Window but the problem is that the content on the info window for all the markers is showing the content meant for the last marker in the table. Below is the code:

```
<?php
include("php/db.php");
$db = new dbAccess($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass, $db_db, true);
$db->query("select * from tbl_gps;", false);
    while($row_gps = $db->fetchrow()){
        $gps_list .= "['".$row_gps['gps_title']."', ".$row_gps['lat_dec'].", ".$row_gps['long_dec'].", ".$row_gps['gps_order']."],\n";
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Aerial View Of Federal Polytechnic Bauchi</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.256817, 9.771996),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                myOptions);

  setMarkers(map, struct);
}

/**
 * Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for
 * the order in which these markers should display on top of each
 * other.
 */
var struct = [
<?php echo $gps_list; ?>

];
var markers = new Array();
function setMarkers(map, locations) {
 var infowindow = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var location = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: location[0],
        zIndex: location[3]
    });

/* now inside your initialise function */
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: "holding..."
});


google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

// where I have added .html to the marker object.
infowindow.setContent(location[0]);
infowindow.open(map, this);
});

    }


}
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#000" onload="initialize()">

  <div id="map_canvas" style="height:95%; width:100%"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your code has the problem with javascript closure. It's the common problem when attaching event listeners in the loop. Try to understand and follow http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure.html.